# can the material for kinect xbox360 be applied on kinect xbox one?

Tags: kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hey there ,  i wanted to use kinect of xbox one connected to my pc in my graduation project , but the material on internet are about kinect of xbox 360 , my question is , can these material be applied on kinect xbox one ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225338/can-the-material-for-kinect-xbox360-be-applied-on-kinect-xbox-one?/) by [mohm](https://answers.ros.org/users/25766/mohm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-01-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Depends on what material you are referring to.

Both devices are capable of producing point clouds and depth maps. So if you are interested in doing a project with 3D machine vision (perhaps using OpenCV or PCL), there isn't really a difference in the mathematics involved. For getting this data into ROS, you could use [freenect_launch](http://wiki.ros.org/freenect_launch) or [openni_launch](http://wiki.ros.org/openni_launch) for Kinect XBox 360, or you could use [kinect2_bridge](https://github.com/code-iai/iai_kinect2) for the Kinect 2 (Kinect for XBox One).

If you are trying to do skeleton tracking with NITE, that is a bit of a different story. The XBox 360 Kinect can easily be made to work with [openni_tracker](http://wiki.ros.org/openni_tracker), but AFAIK OpenNI2 doesn't yet support Kinect 2 (although [people are trying](https://github.com/occipital/OpenNI2/pull/46)). This means that it is likely difficult to get the new Kinect working with skeleton tracking in Linux/ROS. You could potentially use Microsoft SDKs and transfer the necessary data to a ROS/Linux computer over a network or even try to run ROS on a Windows computer, but IMO these options are not out-of-the-box solutions.

The devices certainly have different capabilities, and there are pros and cons to each. The old Kinect (360) is a structured light sensor and the new Kinect (One) is a time-of-flight sensor. The new one is higher resolution, more accurate, and less sensitive to surface conditions and ambient lighting. At the same time, the new Kinect produces far more data, often requiring offloading computational burdens to a GPU. This also means that it can be far more difficult to get the new Kinect running.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2016-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mohm](https://answers.ros.org/users/25766/mohm/) on 2016-01-29**:
thanks for your reply
actually , our team want to use it in mapping and image processing , could you plz give a hint ,
thank you  very much

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2016-01-30**:
Kinect for XBox One should work fine for that. Be aware though that it does require more processing than the old Kinect.

**Comment by [mohm](https://answers.ros.org/users/25766/mohm/) on 2016-02-03**:
thank you sir